# NVMe VPD access failed

Tags: linux, storage, pci-express, nvme

I get `nvme 0000:01:00.0: VPD access failed. This is likely a firmware bug on this device.  Contact the card vendor for a firmware update` in my kernel log sometimes. However SMART data and NVMe self-tests are fine. Kernel sources suggest NVMe drivers don't need PCIe VPD section at all.

What are potential stability/performance implication of this?